# Writing objects to plain text in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I write an object to NSUserDefaults as plain text?

I've written a unit conversion system for a scientific application that basically operates around the principal of "unit objects". These objects represent a specific unit with a specific value in a given domain. The domain is represented by the class name, since everything is organized so that a time unit is literally called "TimeUnit" and a length unit is literally called "LengthUnit".

The current value of a "unit" is represented by a double, and the "unit" itself (ie, "meters", "kelvin", "hours", "pounds", etc) is represented by an NSString.

I need to be able to write these objects to NSUserDefaults.

I've already implemented a system using NSCoding and NSKeyedArchiver. This works great, I can store and retrieve units from NSUserDefaults and everything works.

The problem is that the output from NSKeyedArchiver is too big. The base64 encoded data you get from it is this gigantic chunk of characters, which is impossible to change through a plain text editor and somewhat difficult to debug. I know you can override this to a certain extent by using NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 with NSKeyedArchiver's setOutputFormat, but even that produces a fairly verbose output with a whole bunch of stuff I don't really care about (I know all that data is there for a reason, but I'm guessing that's because NSKeyedArchiver is designed to handle a lot of different situations).

It would be much easier if I could encode these objects using my own format. Something almost like:

```
class_name:double_value:unit_name
```

So a temperature unit with a value of 22 degrees celsius would become:

```
TemperatureUnit:22:celsius
```

What is the best way of achieving something like this? Should I be subclassing NSCoder? Will this let me store the objects as a plain text string in NSUserDefaults and not a base64 encoded chunk of binary data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like this you could add "serialize" and "deserialize" methods (or whatever names you want). The former returns a string and the latter takes a string and returns your object.

```
+ (MyUnitClass *)deserialize:(NSString *)encodedString {
    // split string, create new object, assign values
}

- (NSString *)serialize {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%f:%@", self.classname, self.double_value, self.unit_name];
}
```

Now you can call `serialize` on one of your objects and store the string in `NSUserDefaults`. Use `deserialize` to create an object from a string you have stored in `NSUserDefaults`.